# Recursive Operation and then jump out of the loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have an object which stores department hierarchy. Each department might have sub department as well. I am trying to loop to check all department and also sub(child) department properties are `Open`.

However, whenever I hit recursive call, it only iterates once and jump directly to `return true`, even though there are still some items which has not checked in the loop yet.

```
validateDepartment(departmentHierarchy: any) {
      for (let dept of departmentHierarchy.children) {
          if (dept!= undefined && dept!= null) {
            if (dept.instance.status == "Open")
            {
              continue
            }
            else
            {
                if (dept.children != undefined && dept.children != null) {
                    this.validateDepartment(dept);
                }
                else {
                    return false
                }
            }
          }
      }
      return true
  }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the structure of `departmentHierarchy`, is `departmentHierarchy.department` the same as `departmentHierarchy`? If not, that could be causing the issue.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, sorry there was a typo in the code after reading your comment. I have fixed. could you please check again?

Comment: Looks like you just forgot a `return` before your recursion call, but... where is the actual code that "does" anything in this? Normally you'd want some kind of result returned that tells you which thing, and where in the tree, failed validation (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Not part of any answer, but it helps to only write the code that "does" things, rather than having lots of code that does "what the code would already do anyway", such as calling a `continue` when the iteration code is a single if/else. We can rewrite your code to this, and have something easier to work with:

```
validateDepartment(tree: any) {
  // step 1: do any validation of the top node
  if (!validateTopNodeOnly(tree)) {
    // this is a stop condition.
    return false;
  }

  if (!tree.children) {
    // this is also a stop condition, but for a different reason.
    // a department without children should not _necessarily_ be invalid.
    return true? return false? probably return true since the node itself is fine.
  }

  if (tree.instance && tree.instance.status !== "open") {
    // and this is a third  condition, but for yet another reason.
    // I'm guessing this is also not "invalid", just means we shouldn't recurse.
    return true? return false? probably return true as well.
  }

  // Then, get all (non-falsey) children,
  let children = tree.children.filter(e => e);

  // and iterate over them:
  for (let e of children) {
    let result = this.validateDepartment(e);

    // cut your run short if validation fails
    if (result === false) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // and this is the expected stop condition for a normal run.
  return true;
}
```

But using true/false is incredibly naive and won't tell you anything about *where* validation failed, so you'll want to work in "what failed", typically by returning a reference to the actual "thing that's getting validated" so that if your function returns `true`, all is well, and it returns something `!== true` then you know it failed, and the thing it returned is the department where things went wrong.

Also note that by using an early return on validation failure, you're missing out on information: instead it's way better to use `.map()` and construct a running tally of all deparments that pass/fail validation, so that you return an array in which either `result.every(e => (e===true))` is true, or is false, in which case `result.filter(e => (e!==true))` gives you the set of every single failed department.

Answer (score 0):

```
  isopen = this.validateDepartment(this.departmentHierarchy);

  validateDepartment(dept: any): boolean {
    let result=(dept.instance.status == "Open");
    if (result) {
      if (dept.children) {
        dept.children.forEach(x => {
          result = result && this.validateDepartment(x)
        })
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```